Current tag synonym candidates
I suggest adopting the following system for handling tags that could be made synonyms. The system has worked well on Cross Validated: see here.

Please post your tag synonym suggestions as new answers in this thread, one answer per suggestion. Upvote answers where you believe that the suggested tags should be made synonyms, and downvote answers where you believe the tags should remain separate. Well upvoted suggestions will be eventually implemented by the moderators (and then the corresponding answers will be deleted).

estimation (145) $\leftarrow$ parameter-estimation (56), 8 overlapping.
Since the estimand is typically a parameter, I do not think we need both of the tags. (And if the estimand is a realization of a random variable rather than a parameter, the action of obtaining it from the data is no longer called estimation but rather fitting, prediction or forecasting.)

yahoofinance (56) $\leftarrow$ yahoo (30), 6 overlapping.
Is there any difference between the two?

In the context of Quantitative Finance SE, is there a sufficient difference between mathematics (193) and finance-mathematics (412) (88 overlapping)? If there is, could anyone explain it and accordingly edit the tag descriptions to make it easier to decide which one is appropriate when? And if there is not, let us make them synonyms.
(Financial-mathematics would make more sense to me than finance-mathematics, but that is another issue.)
